# Set D3 ticks dynamically based on data range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to dynamically set `ticks` on a D3 axis based on the current data set. The issue that I'm running into is that my time range (x-axis) can vary widely. For some datasets it is several years worth, for others a couple months, and in some cases just milliseconds. I currently have this set for `ticks`:

```
.ticks(d3.time.month, 3)
```

...which displays every third month. This is a nice quarterly axis for data spanning many months or years. However in cases where the data only ranges over a couple weeks, days, or even seconds nothing appears on my axis labels.

Comment: why not simply check witch time interval fit the best on your dataset (second, minutes, month,...) and just use the appropriate https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals ?

Comment: From the `d3` [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales):  `Most conveniently, the time scale also provides suitable ticks based on time intervals, taking the pain out of generating axes for nearly any time-based domain.`  So just remove  your `.ticks(d3.time.month, 3)` and let `d3` decide for you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my (rather extensive) experience, there's no auto-magical way to do it. But the "hard" way, in which you explicitly specify what you want to happen for any time range, is very effective.

Basically, you know the full time span of the graph — let's say it's called `timeSpan` and it's in terms of milliseconds — so you can make a large if...else block that responds to it. For example

```
var interval, count;
if (timeSpan <= 3600000) { // 1 hour or less
  interval = d3.time.minute;
  count = 15; // every 15 minutes
}
else if (timeSpan <= 8.64e7) { // 24 hours {
  interval = d3.time.hour;
  count = 1;
}
else if (timeSpan <= 7 * 8.64e7) { // 7 days {
  interval = d3.time.day;
  count = 1;
}
// etc....

timeAxis.ticks(interval, count);
```

That has worked very well for me in many scenarios. You can expand on it as needed, by adding more conditions as needed. Also, maybe your graph has two axes — one for primary, labeled ticks and the other for secondary ticks or grid lines. Then you can introduce another variable, `secondaryInterval` and work that into the if...else block in the same way. Similarly, you'll likely find that you also need to specify `.tickFormat()` differently per `timeSpan` and that can be worked into this code as well.

```
var interval, count, format;
if (timeSpan <= 3600000) { // 1 hour or less
  interval = d3.time.minute;
  count = 15; // every 15 minutes
  format = d3.time.format("%H:%M");
}
// etc....
timeAxis
  .ticks(interval, count)
  .tickFormat(format);
```

Also, if your chart is responsive, meaning that sometimes it's 900 pixels wide and at others it's 200 pixels wide, you might want to adjust the ticks based on the density as well. In that case, you'll want to compute a density value like "milliseconds per pixel":

```
msPerPixel = timeSpan / chartWidth
```

For any given `timeSpan`, `msPerPixel` would be smaller or larger depending on the browser (or chart's) width, and you can use `msPerPixel` to refine the conditional logic above to show more or less ticks depending on `msPerPixel` being greater than some constant.

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: you made me question my comment above.  [What's wrong with `d3`s internal algorithm for this](http://plnkr.co/edit/DiRpexDvqxIaR1LyWWOo?p=preview)?

Comment: @Mark I've found that letting d3 decide the ticks never quite gets you what you want nor works for all time ranges. That's especially the case when `.tickFormat` is involved as well. D3 picks different tick formats for each tick in the same chart (like a tick labeled 2015 next to a tick labeled February), which is neat but usually unhelpful. Also, d3  doesn't factor the width of the chart into the tick selection, so it can't ensure the tick labels won't overlap and it won't pick more or less ticks depending on width. Bottom line, it's not too hard to be explicit, and it seems worth it.